# What does "walk the abstract syntax tree" mean?

Tags: ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm in a compilers class, in which we have to write a compiler in OCaml, and I keep hearing that a necessary step is "walking the abstract syntax tree." What does that mean, both theoretically, and in terms of actually writing code?

Comment: @Thomas Since it's a compilers class, not an interpreters class, I would not expect anything to be evaluated. There are a lots of reasons why you'd want to walk an AST other than evaluating it.

Comment: It is synonymous with “traversing” in this context: you need to traverse the AST. One reason to do so may be to decorate the AST with types. In terms of actually writing code, a recursive function that pattern-matches on the constructions of the abstract syntax would probably be involved.

Answer (score -1):

It means you need to take an AST and walk through the nodes to do something, just like traversing a list. So something like this

```
match ast_token with
| INT_LITERAL(x) -> dsw x
| IF_EXPRESSION(p, e1, e2) -> dsw p e1 e2
...
```